# PostgreSQL Declared Variable in Function

Tags: database, function, postgresql, variables

I work with Potgresql and I have written function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION staging.shape_commit(layer_id integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
declare     
  layer_name text;

begin
layer_name:=(select shape.layer_name from staging.shape where shape.id=layer_id);
delete  from layer_name;
return layer_name;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION staging.shape_commit(integer)
  OWNER TO test;
```

layer_name is variable and really it is table name .but script ignore it as variable and uses as string

Cam anybody help me?

Comment: Shouldn't you be returning text?

Comment: I just want to Postgresql understand layer_name as variable not as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't quite clear, but I suspect that you actually want to convert the text to a table name. For this, you want dynamic SQL. Instead of:

```
delete  from layer_name;
```

Try something more like:

```
execute $x$delete from $x$ || layer_name::regclass;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html